# redircct if user is not authencate on custom page in drupal

Tags: drupal

hi i want to redirect the user on custom page  if he clicks on any such page for he is not authenticate. how can i do this.is there any custom module for this. or please give some guide line for this.

Comment: User Custom error Module Provided By the Drupal this is the url http://drupal.org/project/customerror (I have found it and working great)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Rules module to do this.